# Ticks only at the start and end of an axis

Tags: javascript, visualization, d3.js

I'm new to using D3. I'd like to only put ticks on an axis at the start and the end. How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure how this is not a real question; The D3 author understood the question fine. Could you explain why you feel this question is vague? I'll re-phrase if necessary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The minimum and maximum value (the domain extent) are part of the domain path, so one option is to set [axis.ticks](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-ticks) to zero to hide the ticks and only show the domain path. For example:

- http://bl.ocks.org/2996766

However, the domain path doesn't include text labels for the values. So, for that, you could instead set [axis.tickValues](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickValues) to the minimum and maximum value for explicit ticks:

- http://bl.ocks.org/2996785